# How to use scanf in a loop to save characters in an array using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

I am trying to use pointers to save characters to an array but when I run the program, it saves all but the last character and instead replaces it with something random.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputCharArray(char *beg, char *end){
    char *current = beg;

    while (current != end) {
        scanf("%c ", current);
        current++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int size, position;
    position = 0;

    printf("Size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    char letters[size];

    printf("Array: ");

    inputCharArray(&letters[0], &letters[size]);

    printf("%s", letters);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is what I get when I run the program:

```
Size of array: 3
Array: a s d

as▒
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: So I added       end = '\0';         after the while loop and it didn't change the outcome. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `'\0'` string terminator written to `letters[]`

In `main` you need

```
char letters[size + 1];          // allow for terminator
```

and the function should be

```
void inputCharArray (char *beg, char *end){
    char *current = beg;

    while (current != end){
        scanf(" %c", current);   // moved the space to other side of %c
        current++;
    }
    *current = '\0';             // added string terminator
}
```

I also changed `scanf("%c ", current);` to `scanf(" %c", current);` because it was reading the [newline left in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer) after `%d` format specifier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made those changes and it got rid of the random character at the end, but it didn't save the last character. So if I entered "a s d " it just saved "as"

Comment: The change to scanf(" %c", current); got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most `scanf` format specifiers automatically filter out leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` do not. A space before `%c` and `%[]` tells `scanf` to do that.